# Angular2: ElementRef nativeElement vs querySelector performance

Tags: angular

There are times when I have to go for `DOM event listners` and since

I'm more familiar with `querySelector` I can use it with more ease.

But I wonder what does `ElementRef` has to offer and which one is better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ElementRef` and `Renderer` provide an abstraction of a part of the DOM API which allows to execute some DOM related actions when no actual browser DOM is available like it is the case when the Angular application is executed by the server or in a WebWorker. Not using this abstraction might prevent your application to utilize server-side-rendering or WebWorkers.

Comment: Does it mean that if `ElementRef` is used, Google Bot might still render the application and otherwise not ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/universal allows server side rendering and needs to set up on the server. If you do, Google Bots and browser clients get prerendered HTML from Angular components. Just using `ElementRef` and `Renderer` doesn't provide anything by itself. If you use them instead of direct DOM access your chances are much higher your Application will be compatible with Angular2 Universal or WebWorkers in case you want to enable this features eventually.

Comment: So I can safely deduct that in current scenario it doesn't make a difference since we don't have any plans of server-side-rendering. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, if you don't plan to use server-side-rendering or WebWorkers you can as well use `elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector()` or `document.querySelector()` or jQuery, ...

Comment: Does it imply that we must plan ? otherwise why use Angular.  or just lists the infinite options ?

Comment: Not sure what to make from your last comment. I guess my translation from German to English wasn't optimal. "If you don't intend to use server-side-rendering or WebWorkers, .... " there is no need to use them. They are beneficial in some scenarious but I don't know enough about your situation to give much advice.

Comment: No, your translation is perfect. I just thought that it was blunt but now I know that it's translated from German. So, no complains. Cheers ;)

Comment: is there any performance related issue when we use document.querySelector ?

Comment: @jaibalaji no, there is no performance difference. The same code is called. The difference ist only, that for Serverside rendering the DOMs `querySelector` is not available and there `Renderer` is replaced by an implementation that does nothing to not cause an error.