# Native Element in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I was working on a project recently and I came across a line

`this.sendImageButton.nativeElement.disabled = true;`

This seemed to be alright to me until a colleague pointed out that using the native element is not safe. He meant that accessing the element like this is not considered a good practice. I want to know that why is it not safe to access it like this? Also, what are the possible alternatives to access it then?

As of now, I am using Renderer to access it but even that contains a native element. How is it different from the one mentioned above?

`this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.sendImageButton.nativeElement, 'background-color', "Blue");`

Hoping for a quick response. Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between using angular 2 renderer and using nativeElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821936/difference-between-using-angular-2-renderer-and-using-nativeelement)

Answer (score 4):

Accessing or passing `nativeElement` isn't unsafe, it's only potentially unsafe. It depends on what you do with it.
If you use it to set `innerHTML`, then you're circumventing the `DomSantitizer` Angular uses when you for example use `<div [innerHTML]="someHtml"`. Therefore your application is becoming more prone to XSS. There might be others as well.

Using `nativElement` isn't anymore unsafe than using the browser by itself, just what you do with it defines whether it might make your application more vulnerable or not.

If you access properties of `nativeElement` like `nativeElement.style...` or `nativeElement.className...` your application won't be compatible with server-side-rendering (Universal) or Angulars web worker feature, because when Angular code is run in such environments, these properties won't be available. This is also why the `Renderer2` or `Renderer` don't provide any method to read information from the DOM (only to update the DOM)